# Is There an Archiving Library Without Dependencies? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, tar, archive

Hey, I'm looking for an archiving library that functions like GNU's tar, but without any dependencies. I need some sort of archiving format to manage resources in my game engine and am still iffy about rolling my own.

Comment: what do you mean by not any dependencies?

Comment: For archiving, do you simply need to pack some stuff into your executable or are you more interested in compression?

Comment: I'm not really interested in packing things into the executable yet. I just wanted to implement an easier way to manage resources such as sprites and sounds, and an archive format like tar seems to be the best thing. Compression is optional, as implementing a basic run length compression algorithm is trivial. By dependencies I mean it should work on any platform, or at least the major ones (Linux, Mac, Windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the BSD [libarchive](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/)

Comment: And that's just what the doctor ordered. Thanks Steven!

Answer (score 0):

You mean for.. files? If yes I don't understand what's wrong with tar?

If you mean for your data structures (I see the question is tagged as C++) then try [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Comment: Not for data structures, for resources.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with tar. I just need an implementation without any dependencies. Steven provided that, so thanks anyway.